# How to count query with distinct records?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query with DISTINCT columns.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT column_1
    column_2,
    column_3,
    column_4,
    column_5,
    column_6,
    column_7,
    column_8,
    column_9
FROM 
    my_table 
WHERE 
    column_4 IN(some array) 
    and ... 
    order by column_1, column_2
```

This query is correct which returns some 1000 records. Now I need to find out total number of records using count.

I have tried select count(DISTINCT column_1) but the count record is not 1000.

I can apply count the records from PHP but I am looking to do it from query itself.

Can anybody please teach me how to write count query?

Comment: What is the exact final output you want here?

Comment: Display the count means 1000 for above case.

Answer (score 2):

`COUNT(DISTINCT column_1)` only counts the number of distinct `column_1` values. To get the number of results that are in your query, you need to apply [`COUNT(DISTINCT...)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct) to all the columns:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4, ... column_9)
FROM my_table 
WHERE ...
```

Note that this is a MySQL extension to SQL and will not work on other DBMS.

Comment: Ohh thats easy . I was trying group by .... making things complex myself.  Thanks anyways.

Comment: It won't count combinations that include a `NULL` value, but otherwise, yes.